# How do i impletment these two scritpts togeather

Tags: javascript, json

im very new to JS and i found some code snippets online on some image carosels and i wrote another script that takes in a dict of inforation and converts it to a gui and i want to combine the two so it will show a carosel of these slide things

i havent gotten far at all these are the two scripts

this is the image carosel

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            height: 100vh;
            display: grid;
            place-items: center;
        }

        .slider {
            width: 1000px;
            height: 500px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .slide {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            transition: all 0.5s;
        }

        .slide img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }

        .btn {
            position: absolute;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 50%;
            z-index: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: white;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        .btn:active {
            transform: scale(1.1);
        }

        .btn-prev {
            top: 45%;
            left: 2%;
        }

        .btn-next {
            top: 45%;
            right: 2%;
        }

        .dot-indicator {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .dot {
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            margin: 0 5px;
            border-radius: 50px;
            background-color: gray;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }

        .dot.active {
            background-color: black;
            width: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?landscape,mountain" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?landscape,cars" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?landscape,night" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?landscape,city" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?landscape,mountain" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?landscape,cars" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?landscape,night" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?landscape,city" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?landscape,mountain" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?landscape,cars" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?landscape,night" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?landscape,city" alt="" /></div>
        <button class="btn btn-next">></button>
        <button class="btn btn-prev">p</button>
    </div>
    <div class="dot-indicator"></div>
    <script>
        "use strict";
        const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
        slides.forEach((slide, i) => slide.style.transform = `translateX(${i * 100}%)`);
        const nextSlide = document.querySelector(".btn-next");
        let curSlide = 0, maxSlide = slides.length - 1;
        nextSlide.addEventListener("click", () => moveSlide(1));
        const prevSlide = document.querySelector(".btn-prev");
        prevSlide.addEventListener("click", () => moveSlide(-1));
        function moveSlide(dir) {
            curSlide = (curSlide + dir + slides.length) % slides.length;
            slides.forEach((slide, i) => slide.style.transform = `translateX(${(i - curSlide) * 100}%)`);
            updateDotIndicator();
            resetTimer();
        }
        function updateDotIndicator() {
            const dots = document.querySelectorAll(".dot");
            dots.forEach((dot, i) => dot.classList.toggle("active", i === curSlide));
        }
        let idleTimer = null;
        function resetTimer() {
            clearTimeout(idleTimer);
            idleTimer = setTimeout(() => moveSlide(1), 3000);
        }
        function initDotIndicator() {
            const dotIndicator = document.querySelector(".dot-indicator");
            for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                const dot = document.createElement("div");
                dot.classList.add("dot");
                if (i === 0) dot.classList.add("active");
                dot.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    curSlide = i;
                    slides.forEach((slide, j) => slide.style.transform = `translateX(${(j - curSlide) * 100}%)`);
                    updateDotIndicator();
                    resetTimer();
                });
                dotIndicator.appendChild(dot);
            }
        }
        initDotIndicator();
        resetTimer();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is the card system

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
      font-weight:  600;
    }

    #container {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: red;
    }

    #container .article-slider {
      background-color: blue;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
    }

    .image-banner {
      width: 70%;
      height: 100%;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: start;
    }

    .image-banner .top {
      width: 100%;
      height: 10%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .image-banner .top .tag-item {
      margin-left: 10px;
      width: 90px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      border-radius: 20px;
      height: 25px;
      backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
      color:white;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      transition: all 0.7s;
    }

    .image-banner .downloads {
      width: 25%;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      margin-left: 10px;
      width: 140px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      border-radius: 20px;
      height: 25px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
      color:white;
      transition: all 0.7s;
    }
    .description{
      width: 30%;
      height: 100%;
    } .blur-layer {
      width:100%; 
      height:100%;
      display:flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      backdrop-filter: blur(100px);
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    } .content-card {
      width:85%; 
      height:90%;
      border-radius: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .blur-layer-two{
      width:100%; 
      height:100%;
      backdrop-filter: blur(100px);
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
      border-radius: 10px;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      display:flex;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    } .blur-layer-two .title {
      width:100%; 
      height:15%;
      color:white;
      display:flex;
      align-items: end;
      justify-content:center;
      font-size:24px;
    } .blur-layer-two .descriptions {
      width:100%;
      height:50%; 
      color:rgb(124, 124, 124);
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 15px;
    } .blur-layer-two .download {
      width:90%; 
      height:10%; 
      background-color:transparent; 
      color:rgb(138, 138, 138);
      border:none; 
      outline:none;
      border-radius: 20px;
      transition: all 0.7s;
    } .blur-layer-two .download:hover, 
    .image-banner .downloads:hover, 
    .image-banner .tag-item:hover {
      color:white;
      background-color: #4f1df5;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script>
    function appendArticleToContainer(articleData, containerId) {
      const container = document.getElementById(containerId);
      const template = `
        <div class="article-slider">
          <div class="image-banner" style="background-image: url(${articleData["image-url"]})">
            <div class="top"></div>
            <div class="downloads">${articleData["downloads"]} Downloads</div>
          </div>
          <div class="description" style="background-image: url(${articleData["image-url"]}">
            <div class="blur-layer">
              <div class="content-card" style="background-image: url(${articleData["image-url"]}"> 
                <div class="blur-layer-two"> 
                  <div class="title">${articleData.title}</div>
                  <div class="descriptions">${articleData.description}</div>
                  <button class="download">Download</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      `;

      container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template);

      const topDiv = container.querySelector('.top');
      articleData.tags.forEach(tag => {
        const tagItem = document.createElement('div');
        tagItem.classList.add('tag-item');
        tagItem.textContent = tag;
        topDiv.appendChild(tagItem);
      });
    }

    const jsonData = {
      "article dict": {
        "title": "this is my title",
        "author": "John Doe",
        "image-url": "https://cc-prod.scene7.com/is/image/CCProdAuthor/Module%204_Pod%203@2x?$png$&jpegSize=200&wid=836",
        "description": "dis is my description heheheha",
        "downloads": 12345,
        "tags": ["app", "tool", "utility"]
      }
    };

    appendArticleToContainer(jsonData["article dict"], 'container'); // Replace 'container' with the ID of your container element
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```